# multiple consumers with latest and earliest offset options with spring-kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

There's one consumer with `earliest` offset option and batch processing which works perfectly fine.

Now there's need to add another consumer which should work in single processing mode and always look for `latest` offset - this one appears to be in clash with some of configs below because it doesn't really have messages processed.

properties for whole application:

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=${KAFKA_ADDRESS:localhost:9092}
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group
spring.kafka.listener.type=batch
spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.max-poll-records=100000
```

bean for working consumer:

```
@Bean("batchKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> batchKafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    return factory;
}
```

bean for problem consumer:

```
@Bean("singleKafkaListenerContainerFactoryManualCommit")
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> singleKafkaListenerContainerFactoryManualCommit(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setKafkaConsumerProperties(props);
    factory.setBatchListener(false);
    return factory;
}
```

Both consumers are up and running as follows:

```
[ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-2, groupId=group] Successfully joined group with generation 15
[ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group-1, groupId=group] Successfully joined group with generation 15
```

they do target same topic but assuming that there are separate consumer groups in play this shouldn't affect anything in this case.

Maybe there's tricky problem of consumer waiting to poll entire batch or another option interference plays out?

*UPD*
Based on comments this can be done via plain and simple separate consumer group addition.

This is how I've figured to amend properties for new consumer group creation:

```
props.put("group.id", "group-single");
```

and another option:

```
props.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group-single");
```

Still logs indicate no presence of new consumer however.

Comment: Why both of your consumers are in the same group? Of course only one of them is going consumer records from a single partition.

Comment: Why are we assuming they are in separate groups? Your config/code doesn't show this

Comment: thx for input, updated

Comment: If you are still having problems, post a complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) someplace, that exhibits the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This one turns out to be solved by adding this one instead of props map:

```
factory.getContainerProperties().setClientId("consumer-group-other-1");
factory.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("consumer-group-other");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the way of overriding kafka consumer properties that provided through kafka auto configuration, It seem to me that you created a new consumer properties object. which will override the all properties.

the below method **kafkaListenerContainerFactory** in **KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration** class, which is a part of Kafka auto configuration

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = {"kafkaListenerContainerFactory"})
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ObjectProvider<ConsumerFactory<Object, Object>> kafkaConsumerFactory) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        configurer.configure(factory, (ConsumerFactory)kafkaConsumerFactory.getIfAvailable(() -> {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties());
        }));
        return factory;
    }
```

So you have to autowire kafkaProperties and appened whatever you want.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class CustomKafkaConsumerConfig {
    @Autowired
    KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer, ObjectProvider<ConsumerFactory<Object, Object>> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        //configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory.getIfAvailable(() -> new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerFactory()));

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        
        //change Ack mode for example
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>(kafkaProperties.buildConsumerProperties());

        //change offset reset and assignment strategy for example
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RoundRobinAssignor.class.getName());
        return props;
    }
}
```

here is the log:

```
...
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092, localhost:9093, localhost:9094]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = consumer-test-topic-listener-group-1
client.rack = 
....
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
...
```